# How do you recover a rolled back change set in TFS?

Tags: tfs, rollback

In Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, I accidentally checked in a not-compiling, work-in-progress changeset that I intended to shelve in order for a co-worker to take. I rolled back the change set right away. Bad me.

Is there a way to recover that bad/rolled-back changeset as a Pending Changes so that I (or my co-worker) may continue to work on it? I didn't see anything in the UI and had to manually pull out each file and construct the pending changes by hand. It was only 20 minutes of work to code it originally, so not that big a deal (it was my error) but I'm curious if there was a better way.

Comment: This is admittedly not a normal use case, so maybe there is no solution apart from manually digging out each file. Also, I'm curious how often people make this mistake. I have been using Visual Studio and TFS for years and haven't done so before, but then again I don't create shelvesets very often. The check-in and shelf UI are very similar looking.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck on an ancient TFS server that doesn't natively support rollback - but does the rollback not generate a new changeset that is actually committed to achieve the rollback? If so, does the tooling not let you generate a rollback of *that* changeset?

Comment: I was a bit annoyed and on tilt when it happened. But yeah, that would probably work! Thanks

Comment: Also (unrelated) Visual Studio introduced rollback in (I think) Visual Studio 2013. But TFS has supported it for quite a while via the command line. Depending how ancient your TFS is, it might have it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, I still live in a 2008 world (for the server) and so have to use the power tools version. I knew it become native later but I'm only (unfortunately) familiar with the 2008 variant. That's why I wasn't confident enough to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As was said in the comments, you can "rollback the rollback".  I do it all the time.  Just find the rollback changeset in history, and roll that back, and it will get you your half-finished changes into your local workspace, so you can continue working on them and check them in when done.

Comment: Very useful.. like the concept "rollback the rollback".